# compare two csv files line per line with the output if it is added, deleted or updated

Tags: batch-file

I have two csv files with 5 fields where the seperator is a comma. I need to compare these files and get an output file with the information which lines are added, updated or deleted.

I have found several batch scripts that do a compare using the fc or comp function but that gives only the differences between the files. I didn't find related topics can give the results about added, updated or deleted lines.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: You have not provided enough information to solve your problem. How do you differentiate between an update versus a delete/insert? Does the order of the lines matter? Or is there a primary key for each line? What do you want your results to look like? Once you establish rules, you might be able to implement those rules with a batch file, but it probably would not be my first choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This topic is interesting! Perhaps you, like me, find confusing and annoying the output format of FC command, although it provides the required information indeed. The Batch program below take the output of FC command and rearrange it in a way that allows to identify if a new block of information has been added between two lines of original file, or if a block of lines has been deleted from the original file, or any other case of file modification (updated). The most difficult part was to choose the format to display the information in a pleasant way, but I think my solution is pretty good!

```
@echo off
rem FCOMP.BAT: Format FC output in a pleasant way
rem Antonio Perez Ayala
if "%~2" neq "" goto start
echo Format FC output identifying added, deleted or updated sections
echo/
echo FCOMP filename1 filename2 [/switches /for /FC /command]
goto :EOF

:start
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set while=if not
set do=goto endwhile
set endwhile=goto while
set "space= "
set "spaces39=                                       "
fc %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 %1 %2 > differences.txt
if %errorlevel% equ 1 call :FormatFC < differences.txt
del differences.txt
goto :EOF

:FormatFC
set /P line=
set /P line=
rem Process each set of differences
:while
%while% defined line %do%
   rem Load old and new sections of this set
   set line=
   set /P line=
   set old=0
   :while1
   %while% "!line:~0,5!" neq "*****" %do%1
      set /A old+=1
      set oldLine[%old%]=!line!%spaces39%
      set line=
      set /P line=
   %endwhile%1
   :endwhile1
   set line=
   set /P line=
   set new=0
   :while2
   %while% "!line:~0,5!" neq "*****" %do%2
      set /A new+=1
      set newLine[%new%]=!line!%space%
      set line=
      set /P line=
   %endwhile%2
   :endwhile2
   rem Identify the type of this set
   if %old% equ 2 (
      echo ======  NEW SECTION ADDED  ====================================================
      echo/
      echo(!oldLine[1]:~0,79!
      set /A new-=1
      for /L %%i in (2,1,!new!) do echo(        ^|!newLine[%%i]:~0,70!
      echo(!oldLine[2]:~0,79!
   ) else if %new% equ 2 (
      echo OLD SECTION DELETED  ==========================================================
      echo/
      echo(---------!newLine[1]:~0,70!
      set /A old-=1
      for /L %%i in (2,1,!old!) do echo -!oldLine[%%i]:~0,78!
      echo(---------!newLine[2]:~0,70!
   ) else ( rem both %old% and %new% gtr 2
      echo ==============================  SECTION UPDATED  ==============================
      echo/
      if %old% lss %new% (
         for /L %%i in (1,1,%old%) do echo(!oldLine[%%i]:~0,39!^|!newLine[%%i]:~0,39!
         set /A old+=1
         for /L %%i in (!old!,1,%new%) do echo(%spaces39%^|!newLine[%%i]:~0,39!
      ) else (
         for /L %%i in (1,1,%new%) do echo(!oldLine[%%i]:~0,39!^|!newLine[%%i]:~0,39!
         set /A new+=1
         for /L %%i in (!new!,1,%old%) do echo(!oldLine[%%i]:~0,39!
      )
   )
   rem Pass to next set of differences
   echo/
   set /P line=
   set line=
   set /P line=
%endwhile%
:endwhile
exit /B
```

Antonio

Comment: +1 - Nice Aacini. Can you document the options a bit. I assume the /switches are options for the FC, but I haven't a clue about the other options (/FOR, /FC, /COMMAND). I like the output format, except updates are hard to understand if they occur at the end of a long line. I don't have any suggestion, other then to allow displayed length to exceed 80 chars.

Comment: Wow this a great answer for my problem. Thank you very much

Comment: @dbenham: Thanks, Dave! The options should just read: `[FC switches]`. I am working now trying to solve the problem of long lines...

Comment: @user1809753: You may get the last version of my program from [this site](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3968). It achieve a more exact identification of sections and manage long lines, etc...

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: as pointed out this is a shell scripting option, hopefully it can be of help for others*

Here is one option, I've not checked it for performance with very large files:

```
$ cat file1
1,'adam'
2,'chris'
6,'phil'
3,'charles'

$ cat file2
2,'christopher'
6,'phil'
3,'chuck'
8,'sue',2
4,'mary'
21,'matt'
```

--we assume the CSV file deliminator is a comma and the first field per record is a Primary Key (unique value)

```
$ comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | awk -F , '{if (a[$1]) {print "^"$1","} {a[$1] = $0}}' > data2.txt
```

--updates

```
$ cat data2.txt | grep -E -f - file2
```

--deletes

```
$ cat data2.txt | grep -v -E -f - <(comm -2 -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2))
```

--inserts

```
$ cat data2.txt | grep -v -E -f - <(comm -1 -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2))
```